# How to accept an answer if answers are both correct but different?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

In this question, there are presently two answers. In short, one says *yes*, one says *no*, and I can't really say which one is more correct:

[Does the head-of-state pardon violate separation of powers?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/251/130)

Is this situation, how should I decide what question to accept, if any?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say there are a few options in this and similar scenarios:

1. to keep with the idea of "keep it balanced", create your own answer combining what's said to show both sides. Personally I'd create it as a community wiki so as not to look like I'm trying to steal the rep from the others
2. make a comment on each answer asking if either would consider editing to take into account both arguments
3. make a comment on your question that you would like an answer that takes into account both arguments and leave it open

Comment: Plus 1 for items 1 and 2.  But don't leave the question open, if you (the questioner) feel it has been answered -- even if the correct information is split between answers.

Comment: @BrockAdams Sorry, I think my wording of item 3 may not have helped. I've clarified it, as it was meant to be basically the same as item 2, just with the comment in a different location

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there is not a correct answer, or at minimum it isn't black and white. I'd agree that marking either answer as "accepted" puts a bias on the questioner and perhaps even the site.

It's questions and answers like these that make me feel that all answers should contain references to studies or original sources pertaining to the question, such as the reference to  the Federalist Papers in one answer (that wasn't technically included to make the point).